# How to get browser URL in ajax file

Tags: php, ajax

I want to get browser URL from ajax code
I tried this php code

```
$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]
```

but it returned ajax file url
how could i get browser urlfrom ajax code??

Comment: You could send it to the server side as ajax parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` contains the original url for Ajax requests. At least for requests made via jQuery. I’m not sure if it also works for plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(location).attr('href');
```

This will return you the current page or browser URL.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way you have to knowing the URL of the page which included the JavaScript which triggered the Ajax request is to just ask that page to include it in the data.

e.g., and using jQuery for this example:

```
data: {
    page_url: location,
    and: then,
    the: "rest of your data"
}
```

This can, obviously, be forged by anyone who wants to fake the request… but so could any other means of getting that information.